# Add new jobstream to database

Tags: java, workload-scheduler, tivoli-work-scheduler

I'm trying to add new jobstream to the TWSz AD but I'm getting the error:
AWSJCS011E An internal error has occurred. The error is the following: "java.lang.NullPointerException".

My code looks like this:

```
JobStream jobStream = new JobStream();

            jobStream.setName("DM#JAVA#COND");
            jobStream.setDescription("Auto Test");
            jobStream.setGroup(false);
            jobStream.setOwnerName("USER");
            jobStream.setPriority(1);

            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
            DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse("17-04-2018",formatter);

            jobStream.setValidFrom(dateTime.toDate());


            Job job001 = new Job();
            job001.setName("1");
            job001.setPriority(1);


             ZOSJobDefinition job001ZOSDef = new ZOSJobDefinition();

             job001ZOSDef.setFlowTargetKey(new FlowTargetKey("BEGN"));
             job001ZOSDef.setTaskType(TaskTypes.ZOS_GENERAL_TASK);
             job001ZOSDef.setJclName("START");
             job001ZOSDef.setAutoSubmit(true);
             job001ZOSDef.setAutoRelease(true);
             job001ZOSDef.setNormalElapsedTime(1000L);
             job001ZOSDef.setHighestOkReturnCode(0);


             job001.setJobDefinition(job001ZOSDef);

             jobStream.getJobs().add(job001);
             model.addTWSObject(jobStream, null);
```

Code looks similar to the one from manual.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with TWS SDK when I replaced 9.2 with 9.3 everything started to work.